# How can I iterate over a list with a macro?

Tags: clojure

I am trying to print the documentation for all functions in a given namespace by invoking the following expression in a REPL:

```
(doseq
  [f (dir-fn 'clojure.repl)]
  (doc f))
```

However the invocation of this expression returns `nil` *without printing the documentation to the REPL*. I know this might have to do with `doc` being a macro, but I'm a Clojure novice and am not entirely sure how to understand the problem.

1. Why does this expression return `nil` without printing the documentation?
2. How can this expression be modified so that it prints the documentation for each function in a given namespace?

Thanks!

**Update:** Combined both provided answers:

```
(defn ns-docs [ns']
  (doseq [[symbol var] (ns-interns ns')]
  (newline)
  (println symbol)
  (print "  ")
  (println (:doc (meta var)))))
(ns-docs 'clojure.repl)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would, instead, start here:

- [The Clojure CheatSheet](http://jafingerhut.github.io/cheatsheet/clojuredocs/cheatsheet-tiptip-cdocs-summary.html)
- [ClojureDocs.org](https://clojuredocs.org/)
- [Clojure-Doc.org](http://clojure-doc.org/)   (similar name, but different)
- The API & Reference sections at [Clojure.org](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/)

Note that `doc` is in the namespace `clojure.repl`, which reflects its intended usage (by a human in a repl). Here is some code that will also iterate on a namespace & print doc strings (using a different technique):

```
  (doseq [[fn-symbol fn-var] (ns-interns 'demo.core)]
    (newline)
    (println fn-symbol)
    (println (:doc (meta fn-var))))
```

where `demo.core` is the namespace of interest.

Note that `ns-interns` gives you both a symbol and var like:

```
fn-symbol  => <#clojure.lang.Symbol -main>
fn-var     => <#clojure.lang.Var #'demo.core/-main>
```

The `meta` function has lots of other info you may want to use someday:

```
(meta fn-var)   =>   
<#clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap 
  { :arglists ([& args]), 
    :doc "The Main Man!", 
    :line 9, :column 1, 
    :file "demo/core.clj", 
    :name -main, 
    :ns #object[clojure.lang.Namespace 0x14c35a06 "demo.core"]}>
```

Comment: That's a wide ocean... anything that can help with my specific problem? I'm assuming it has to do with compile-time and run-time, not sure if there's another function I can use to return the docs as data, or a way to expand the macro inline.

Answer (score 2):

While this probably won't help you with answering your question, the problem of evaluating macro's comes up a lot when you are learning Clojure.

Macros are responsible for the evaluation of their arguments. In this case `clojure.repl/doc` will ignore the current lexical context and assume that the symbol `f` that you're giving it is the name of a function you want to see the documentation for. It does this because it's intended to be used at the REPL, and is assuming you wouldn't want to type quotes all the time.

As `f` doesn't exist, it prints nothing. Then `doseq` returns `nil`, since it exists to do something for side effects only - hence starting in `do`. In order to pass an argument to a macro that refuses to respect the lexical context like this, you need to write the code for each element in the list.

You can do this by hand, or by constructing the code as data, and passing it to `eval` to execute. You can do this in an imperative style, using `doseq`:

```
(doseq [f (ns-interns 'clojure.repl)]
  (eval `(doc ~(symbol "clojure.repl" (str (first f))))))
```

or in a slightly more Clojurey way (which will allow you to see the code that it would execute by removing `eval` from the end and running it at the REPL):

```
(->> (ns-interns 'clojure.repl)
     (map #(list 'clojure.repl/doc (symbol "clojure.repl" (str (first %)))))
     (cons `do)
     eval)
```

In both of these we use quote and syntax-quote to construct some code from the list of symbols reflected from the namespace, and pass it to `eval` to actually execute it. [This page on Clojure's weird characters](https://clojure.org/guides/weird_characters) should point you in the right direction for understanding what's going on here.

This an example of why you shouldn't write macro's, unless you've got no other options. Macro's do not compose, and are often difficult to work with. For a more in depth discussion, [Fogus's talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0JXhJyTo5V8) and [Christophe Grand's talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3yvrs9S0RIw) are both good talks.

Comment: Thanks for this! While interesting, macros seem to add in a cognitive context that can be confusing -- especially for beginning Clojure developers. Both of your examples seem to express more about dealing with the context imposed by macros than they do printing docs for functions in a namespace (not critiquing the quality of your answers, just noting the cognitive load macros add to the solution). Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

> Why does this expression return nil without printing the documentation?

Because the `doc` macro is receiving the symbol `f` from your loop, instead of a function symbol directly.

> How can this expression be modified so that it prints the documentation for each function in a given namespace?

```
(defn ns-docs [ns']
  (let [metas (->> (ns-interns ns') (vals) (map meta) (sort-by :name))]
    (for [m metas :when (:doc m)] ;; you could filter here if you want fns only
      (select-keys m [:name :doc]))))

(ns-docs 'clojure.repl)
=>
({:name apropos,
  :doc "Given a regular expression or stringable thing, return a seq of all
        public definitions in all currently-loaded namespaces that match the
        str-or-pattern."}
 ...
)
```

Then you can print those maps/strings if you want.

Comment: Thanks, that's a nice wrapper for the problem!